# Server is too busy

Tags: iis, performance-monitoring, troubleshooting, cpu-usage

We have an advertisement sever which handles loads of requests at a time, however sometimes out of the blues it shows 'Server is too busy' and an 'iisreset' has to be executed in order for the server to get up and running once again.  Also what I noticed is that the CPU clogs at 100% and is barely possible to rectify the problem.

Do you have any suggestions or troubleshooting experience as to how I can tackle this issue?

Should you have any information which you would like to know, please don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

- Put in a profiler and find out what is taking the time. As in: you have a programming issue, or the server is overloaded.
- Get a faster server ;) Unless you have a bug somewhere which triggers waste of tons of processing power (likea request in an endless loop etc.), it could simply be requests queueing up as the server is not ast enough.

I would move that onto a dev machine (virtual) and attach a profiler to debug where my code is actually spending time. This may help you optimize your code.

Comment: thanks for your feedback.  what do you mean exactly by profiler?  i set up performance counters on this server and used the following attributes - Requests Queued, requests rejected and request wait time.. is there something else you would suggest?

Comment: a profiler is a program analyzing the INNERS of an application - yo ucan see exactly WHERE the application spends time. Something the DEVELOPER should use to make sure his program runs efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a quick fix to get your production machine working while you run the profiler on your dev box:
In IIS, right click on the AppPool your site is using, select properties, set the "Recycle worker process" to something less than the default 1740 minutes.
You may have to play with this setting to see how short to make it.

Info from MS on recycling the process is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/24e3c22e-79a9-4f07-a407-dbd0e7f35432.mspx?mfr=true).